# What are these non-generic kernels ending in azure, aws, nvidia, oem, oracle, gcp and how did they get installed?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, oracle, aws, azure

I run Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Dell laptop.

I noticed that I have quite a few kernels that are non-generic, but I don't know how they got installed.

The kernels ending in `-azure`, `-aws`, `-nvidia`, and `-gcp` do not work for me at all. Only the `-lowlatency`, `-oem` and of course `-generic` work for me. Not sure about `-oracle` kernel as I have not tried booting from that one.

I presume that those ending in `-azure` and `-aws` are the so-called cloud-optimised kernels ( https://ubuntu.com/blog/cloud-optimized-linux-kernels ) ? These do not work for me during boot, stuck at either "Loading initial ramdisk" or it cannot read my volume group `vgubuntu`, which I presume makes sense as they are meant for the cloud and not desktop / laptop.

My questions really are :

- How did they get installed when I don't recall specifically choosing / installing these kernels ?
- How do I prevent them from being installed in the future ?
- Also, what are the `-nvidia` and `-gcp` kernels ?

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1031-nvidia                         5.15.0-1031.31                          amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1038-intel-iotg                     5.15.0-1038.43                          amd64        Signed kernel image intel-iotg
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1040-gcp                            5.15.0-1040.48                          amd64        Signed kernel image gcp
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1043-aws                            5.15.0-1043.48                          amd64        Signed kernel image aws
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-82-generic                          5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-82-lowlatency                       5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency
ii  linux-image-5.17.0-1035-oem                            5.17.0-1035.36                          amd64        Signed kernel image oem
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-1027-oracle                         5.19.0-1027.30                          amd64        Signed kernel image oracle
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-50-generic                          5.19.0-50.50                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.0.0-1020-oem                             6.0.0-1020.20                           amd64        Signed kernel image oem
ii  linux-image-6.1.0-1020-oem                             6.1.0-1020.20                           amd64        Signed kernel image oem
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-1003-nvidia                          6.2.0-1003.3~22.04.1+1                  amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-1008-azure                           6.2.0-1008.8~22.04.1                    amd64        Signed kernel image azure
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-1010-aws                             6.2.0-1010.10~22.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image aws
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-1011-lowlatency                      6.2.0-1011.11~22.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-1012-gcp                             6.2.0-1012.12~22.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image gcp
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-31-generic                           6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                                    5.15.0.82.78                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                          6.2.0.31.31~22.04.8                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: You didn't mention how the OS was installed on your laptop. Please, [edit] the question and add some history context.

Comment: "*How did they get installed when...?*" A human with admin permission directly or indirectly, wittingly or unwittingly, instructed apt to install them. Such things happen.

Comment: "*How do I prevent them from being installed in the future ?*" The machine is your servant. It can (and does) prevent most folly by non-admins. It cannot prevent the folly of an admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I installed the nvidia drivers via the "Additional Drivers" on that day :

[image]

... and in the `/var/log/apt/history.log`, it shows it that these non-generic kernels were also installed:

```
Install: linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1041-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1041.47, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1041-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1041.47, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1042-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1042.49, automatic), libnvidia-common-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-1003-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1003.3~22.04.1+2, automatic), linux-image-5.19.0-1027-oracle:amd64 (5.19.0-1027.30, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-1010-aws:amd64 (6.2.0-1010.10~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.2.0-1011-lowlatency:amd64 (6.2.0-1011.11~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-82-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0-82.91, automatic), linux-modules-5.17.0-1035-oem:amd64 (5.17.0-1035.36, automatic), libnvidia-gl-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-gl-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1038-intel-iotg:amd64 (5.15.0-1038.43, automatic), linux-modules-5.19.0-1014-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-1011-lowlatency:amd64 (6.2.0-1011.11~22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1014-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1010.10, automatic), libnvidia-extra-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), nvidia-compute-utils-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), nvidia-driver-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-1012-gcp:amd64 (6.2.0-1012.12~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-6.2.0-1008-azure:amd64 (6.2.0-1008.8~22.04.1, automatic), dctrl-tools:amd64 (2.24-3build2, automatic), linux-image-5.19.0-1014-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-image-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1010.10, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1031-nvidia:amd64 (5.15.0-1031.31, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1045-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1045.52, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-82-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0-82.91, automatic), libnvidia-encode-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-encode-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1014-nvidia:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1014-nvidia:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1040-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.46, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1038-intel-iotg:amd64 (5.15.0-1038.43, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-1009-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1009.9, automatic), linux-image-6.2.0-1009-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1009.9, automatic), nvidia-utils-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.2.0-1008-azure:amd64 (6.2.0-1008.8~22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1042-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1042.49, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-82-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0-82.91, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-82-lowlatency:amd64 (5.15.0-82.91, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1031-nvidia:amd64 (5.15.0-1031.31, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1040-gcp:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.48, automatic), linux-modules-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1010.10, automatic), linux-image-6.2.0-1003-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1003.3~22.04.1+1, automatic), linux-modules-5.19.0-1027-oracle:amd64 (5.19.0-1027.30, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-82-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-82.91, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1043-aws:amd64 (5.15.0-1043.48, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1045-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1045.52, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.2.0-1010-aws:amd64 (6.2.0-1010.10~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1042-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1042.49, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1040-gcp:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.48, automatic), libnvidia-decode-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-decode-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1031-nvidia:amd64 (5.15.0-1031.31, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1043-aws:amd64 (5.15.0-1043.48, automatic), linux-image-5.17.0-1035-oem:amd64 (5.17.0-1035.36, automatic), nvidia-kernel-common-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.0.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.0.0-1020.20, automatic), linux-image-6.2.0-1012-gcp:amd64 (6.2.0-1012.12~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.1.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1020.20, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1040-gcp:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.48, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1040-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.46, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1027-oracle:amd64 (5.19.0-1027.30, automatic), linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-1003-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1003.3~22.04.1+2, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-1011-lowlatency:amd64 (6.2.0-1011.11~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1041-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1041.47, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-1008-azure:amd64 (6.2.0-1008.8~22.04.1+1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1043-aws:amd64 (5.15.0-1043.48, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-82-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-82.91, automatic), linux-modules-6.2.0-1009-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1009.9, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1031-nvidia:amd64 (5.15.0-1031.31, automatic), linux-base-sgx:amd64 (4.5ubuntu9, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-1040-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.46+1, automatic), linux-modules-6.2.0-1010-aws:amd64 (6.2.0-1010.10~22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1040-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.46+1, automatic), linux-modules-6.2.0-1003-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1003.3~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.19.0-1014-nvidia:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1027-oracle:amd64 (5.19.0-1027.30, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-1010-aws:amd64 (6.2.0-1010.10~22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1038-intel-iotg:amd64 (5.15.0-1038.43, automatic), linux-modules-6.0.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.0.0-1020.20, automatic), linux-modules-6.2.0-1012-gcp:amd64 (6.2.0-1012.12~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-6.1.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1020.20, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1014-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-modules-5.19.0-1014-nvidia:amd64 (5.19.0-1014.14, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency:amd64 (5.19.0-1010.10, automatic), libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.17.0-1035-oem:amd64 (5.17.0-1035.36+1, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1041-oracle:amd64 (5.15.0-1041.47, automatic), nvidia-kernel-source-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.0.0-1020.20+1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-1012-gcp:amd64 (6.2.0-1012.12~22.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-compute-535:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-compute-535:i386 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.1.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1020.20, automatic), linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1040-gcp:amd64 (5.15.0-1040.48, automatic), nvidia-firmware-535-535.86.05:amd64 (535.86.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-5.17.0-1035-oem:amd64 (5.17.0-1035.36+1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.0.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.0.0-1020.20+1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1045-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1045.52, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.1.0-1020-oem:amd64 (6.1.0-1020.20, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1043-aws:amd64 (5.15.0-1043.48, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.2.0-1009-nvidia:amd64 (6.2.0-1009.9, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.15.0-1042-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1042.49, automatic), dkms:amd64 (2.8.7-2ubuntu2.2, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1045-azure:amd64 (5.15.0-1045.52, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-1038-intel-iotg:amd64 (5.15.0-1038.43, automatic), linux-modules-6.2.0-1011-lowlatency:amd64 (6.2.0-1011.11~22.04.1, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-1008-azure:amd64 (6.2.0-1008.8~22.04.1+1, automatic)
Remove: libnvidia-common-515:amd64 (525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-common-525:amd64 (525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-driver-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-utils-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-kernel-common-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.19.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1), libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), nvidia-kernel-source-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1), libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
End-Date: 2023-09-02  18:13:38
```

But I guess that begs another question, why would installing the nvidia drivers add these additional non-generic kernels ?