# Discovery kernel update 5.15.0-83_lowlatency won't work with Nvidia 470, How can I revert to 5.15.0-52?

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, kernel

I made a error with Discover update with my Ubuntu 22.04 system. Updated it from linux 5.15.0-52-lowlatency working with 470 nvidia driver to linux 5.15.0-83-lowlatency and it used the nouveau open source driver. I thought no problem I will just use GRUB and boot up on the old kernel and call it good. It will not boot kernel 5.15.0-52-lowlatency.

I thought about a number of things, removing kernels, the only thing I dare to try is revert the kernel back to the old kernel 52, and remove 56 & 83. What is the best way to do that?

I installed Mainline, researching adding removing kernels. ?

Attempt: I booted on the old kernel 5.15.0-52 (recovery mode) had it repair broken packages. It booted onto the old kernel, it told me that nouveau open source driver would be used and to change them. I changed to nvidia 470 driver and rebooted. Went to GRUB selected the old kernel, and it is stuck at the dev/sda2 blinking prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting from the -generic kernel instead of -lowlatency kernel ? Something similar happened to me when I added the nividia drivers ( on 22.04.3 LTS ) :

[What are these non-generic kernels ending in azure, aws, nvidia, oem, oracle, gcp and how did they get installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484455/what-are-these-non-generic-kernels-ending-in-azure-aws-nvidia-oem-oracle-gc)

The -lowlatency kernel for me used the intel driver.
Only the -generic kernel works for me with the proprietary nvidia driver.

Comment: I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Do you think Mainline could remove the two slack kernels and then the old 5.15.52 w nvidia 470 would work again? What generic kernel would work best with latest nvidia driver?